# Android / Admob : need help for mediation with Facebook as third party network

Tags: java, android, facebook, admob, facebook-audience-network

I have problems to implement the Admob mediation with Facebook as third party network.

I followed the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation

So:

- I added the Admob ads to my app (they work properly)
- I downloaded the Facebook Android SDK  from here:
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks

There are many folders in this sdk. I see a AudienceNetwork.aar file and a facebook-android-sdk-4.22.1.aar file. Should I copy them in my project? In the libs directory? How should I then modify my Gradle files?

- The previous link sends me to this page https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.facebook#read for the Facebook adapter ; I understand that I have to add :

maven {

url  "http://google.bintray.com/mobile-ads-adapters-android"

}

to my Gradle repositories {} section
=> done

- Then the Admob explanations tells "include the JAR files in your project's libs folder". I don't have any jar files in the Facebook sdk or for the adapter.
- Then the Admob explanations tells to add:

  'compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])'

to Gradle. Should I change this by 'compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])' ?

- Again in the Admob explanations: "Configure the AndroidManifest.xml file - Add entries to your AndroidManifest.xml file as required by each ad network you intend to use. Instructions from each network can be found on Mediation Networks. " I don't see any explanations on this page or on the pages linked to this page to configure the Manifest :(

I tried to find answers on the net but without any success.

I would be really grateful if you could help us for these steps !

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google finally issued a detailed and complete doc. Here it is : https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook